# optimize table in stored produce using phpMyAdmin causes out of sync error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I get the following error when running the code in phpMyAdmin. NOTE: I can run any other sql code (update, insert, replace) via phpMyAdmin in a stored procedure; but an optimize causes issues.

NOTE: This code works fine when running from CLI.

ERROR: `#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

SQL Code:

```
delimiter //

create procedure update_phppos() 

begin
OPTIMIZE table phppos_items;
end;

//

delimiter ;

-- Execute the procedure
call update_phppos();

-- Drop the procedure
drop procedure update_phppos;
```

Answer (score 2):

For INNODB I was able to do the same thing and it didn't cause an error in php.

Here is what I did:

```
 ALTER TABLE phppos_items FORCE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Often this is the problem:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

But it is not obvious here.

Meanwhile...  Don't use `OPTIMIZE TABLE`; it is almost always useless, especially for InnoDB tables.

Comment: I had to use optimize/alter table force because of a bug I found in mysql < 5.6.24 see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110602/mysql-update-query-almost-5-minutes-slower-in-5-6-vs-5-5